# Mysql copy two columns from two tables

Tags: mysql

I want to copy data from two columns in a 'table1' to another table 'table2' which is empty and has two columns.

```
insert into users_role_map (email,id) select (email,roleId) from usert ;
```

when I try to do this I get the error

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

when I try to do the same thing with just one column I am able to copy the entire column data but not for the two columns simultaneously.Can any one help me out and guide me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `()` from the `SELECT` statement. They are being parsed as though you were going to do an operation on a column like `(id * 9)`, but MySQL then expects only one column inside the `()` as an operand.  In any case, it's a total misinterpretation by the query parser, and you should have no `()`.

```
INSERT INTO users_role_map (email, id)
   SELECT  email, roleId  FROM usert ;
```

Comment: @luckysing_noobster You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're satisfied with an answer, please click the checkmark beside it to accept the answer.